# How to read XML from the internet using a Web Proxy?

Tags: c#, xml

This is a follow-up to this question: [How to load XML into a DataTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647957/how-to-load-xml-into-a-datatable)

I want to read an XML file on the internet into a DataTable. The XML file is here: http://rates.fxcm.com/RatesXML

If I do:

```
public DataTable GetCurrentFxPrices(string url)
{
    WebProxy wp = new WebProxy("http://mywebproxy:8080", true);
    wp.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    wc.Proxy = wp;
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(wc.DownloadData(url));
    DataSet ds = new DataSet("fxPrices");
    ds.ReadXml(ms);
    DataTable dt = ds.Tables["Rate"];
    return dt;
}
```

It works fine. I'm struggling with how to use the default proxy set in Internet Explorer. I don't want to hard-code the proxy. I also want the code to work if no proxy is specified in Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Console.WriteLine(System.Net.WebProxy.GetDefaultProxy().Address.AbsoluteUri); ...

Comment: Works great thanks, although I get a warning that it's deprecated in Visual Web Developer 2010 Express.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following setting to your app.config/web.config to use the system default proxy automatically:

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true"/>
</system.net>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#region Function to get x-rate via proxy
public string fncProxyGetRate(string countryCode)// use 'GBP' for British Pounds
{
    string rtnTxt = "";
    try
    {
        string url = "http://rss.timegenie.com/forex.xml";
        string proxyUrl = "http://xxx.xxx.x.x:8080/";
        string myXratePath = "/forex/data/code[text()='" + countryCode + "']";

        WebProxy wp = new WebProxy(proxyUrl, true);
        wp.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        wc.Proxy = wp;

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(wc.DownloadData(url));
        XmlTextReader rdr = new XmlTextReader(ms);

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(rdr);

        rtnTxt = doc.SelectSingleNode(myXratePath).ParentNode.SelectSingleNode("rate").InnerXml;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        rtnTxt = ex.Message;
    }
    return rtnTxt;
} 
#endregion
```